Номер телефона определяется как "Ремонт бытовой техники"
У меня есть сайт рембытехника.рф. При звонке по телефону мой номер у человека автоматически определялся как "Ремонт бытовой техники". Потом я сделал много поддоменов и теперь мой номер определяется как "Ремонт бытовой техники (и какой то населенный пункт)", конкретно сечас "Ремонт бытовой техники Советский". Как мне сделать так чтобы было как раньше "Ремонт бытовой техники" без названий населенного пункта. Если поменяю номер на поддомене Советский, он опять поменяется на какой то другой, с другим названием населенного пункта. Так что это не выход.

"При звонке" КАК? Через обычную мобильную сеть? Тогда это вопрос к оператору.

Нет не к оператору. Потому что если в коде сайта поменять номер он будет определяться уже по другому. Оператор тут не при чём, если мыслить логически.

@ronga наверное потому, что другой номер телефона другой, следовательно и хозяин у другого телефона другой?

@ronga если мыслить логически, но название передаёт оператор. Откуда, как и почему он его вообще берёт (наверняка у вас какой-то договор есть) - вопросы к нему.

Вот именно, оператор берет с сайта. Который раньше был один. Появились поддомены. он подставляет из сайтов на поддомене. Вопрос был как сделать, чтобы было как раньше, брал номер из основного сайта. Никакого договора нет.

Так задайте этот вопрос вашему оператору.

Оператор сообщил что у них нет такой технической возможности. Получается всё таки дело в сайтах. Может кто то знает как сделать чтобы было как раньше. Номер телефона на сайте это кликабельная ссылка. Как сделать чтобы на основном домене эта ссылка была главнее других и тогда оператор будет подставлять просто "ремонт бытовой техники"
